# Obtener asistencia de base de datos

Tags: mysql, php8

Tengo una base de datos que contiene:

| id | cedula | fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1213 | 20/08/2022 |
| 2 | 1214 | 20/08/2022 |
| 3 | 1213 | 20/08/2022 |

Lo que deseo es obtener que el primer registro de ese usuario sea la entrada y el segundo salida un ejemplo de la tabla anterior es:

- 1213 marco entrada y salida.
- 1213 solo marco entrada.

No pido código solo sugerencias de como hacerlo ya que no se me ocurre. no puedo cambiar los datos de la tabla debido que esto me lo exporta un BioMetrico :D

Comment: haciendo uso de MVC con PHP, se me ocurre haz tu modelo y controlador que llame a un SP que liste todos los registros con ID 1213 (te traerá 2 registros), no sé como es en PHP exactamente, pero supongo que no cambiará tanto de otros lenguajes... recibes la 'data' (que es tu tabla con 2 registros de 1213) y el `data[0]` sería la entrada y el `data[1]` la salida. Ah! obviamente en el SP tienes que ponerle un WHERE con la fecha respectiva, sino ahí si botaría más de 2 registros, porque por lo que entiendo solo habrán 2 registros por fecha.

Comment: Ya tengo MVC utilizando laravel, tengo que muestre todos los registro y no diferencia entrada de salida, llevo dias tratando pero no logro, con respecto a la fecha no, de hecho los registros se muestran por mes, imagínate ver de día a día, para saber si falto o no xD

Comment: Bueno, para una área como RRHH ver el día a día es algo necesario jaja, pero bueno.. no sé bien tu caso. En fin, mira, lo que yo hago desde .NET MVC C# es crear mi modelo y controlador que llama a un SP que recibe como parámetros la fecha y el ID, ponte... 1213 y el 20/08/2022 y en el SP me traigo 2 select para que me traiga 2 tablas, en el controlador retorno toda la respuesta como datatable. Desde el front (en mi caso Angular) creo mi servicio, lo relaciono al controlador y uso esa respuesta (datatable) con un array. Uso el .map para filtrarlo y traería el item con las id que identifiquen...

Comment: ... a mis 2 tablas (el datable que me retorna el controller), en este caso item[0] la entrada e item[1] mi salida, al final ya lo mostraría en el front. Es lo que haría.

Comment: No se puede partir de la nada, menos en casos como estos. Me refiero a que debe haber una regla o algo que determine cuál es la entrada y cuál es la salida. Por ejemplo: *en un registro con la misma fecha aquel con `id` menor es la entrada y aquel con `id` mayor es la salida*. ¿Podemos contar con esa regla? Si la respuesta es sí, ¿esa regla es segura? Pregunto, porque es un argumento muy precario para definir una entrada y una salida ... la tabla debería tener quizá una columna que registre el tipo de evento con un código, por ejemplo, `0` entrada, `1` salida.

Comment: La importancia de lo dicho antes es enorme, porque la cosa se puede complicar. Supongamos que se desea contar sólo los entradas, o las salidas ocurridas en la primera semana del mes tal del año tal. Si no tienes algo que identifique con facilidad lo que son entradas o salidas, algo tan sencillo se hará harto complicado. El que recibas los datos de otra parte no es excusa, tú puedes recibir esos datos y alimentar con ellos tu modelo de datos y si ese origen de datos no manda los datos identificados (qué son entradas y qué salidas) no queda otra que requerirle esa información de algún modo.

Comment: @JuanPerez , no habia pensado en eso. Tienes razon, si no hay una base y hay un registro de meses y quiero consultar el actual como sabe cual es la entrada y salida. Pense en hacerle un count al total de registro pero eso no es nada optimo jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de dataset que planteas:

```
CREATE TABLE asistencia(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cedula int,
  fecha date
  );
INSERT INTO asistencia (cedula, fecha) VALUES
  (1213,'2022-08-20'),
  (1214,'2022-08-20'),
  (1213,'2022-08-20');
```

Comenzaría añadiendo algún dato más para ilustrar el problema que me parece que estás describiendo:

```
INSERT INTO asistencia (cedula, fecha) VALUES
  (1214,'2022-08-21'),
  (1214,'2022-08-21');
```

Tenemos a dos asistentes que, el día 20, uno entra y sale y el otro sólo entra; y, el día 21, el primero (1213) ya ni viene. Como nuestro registro no guarda horas, nos tenemos que arreglar únicamente con el día.

En primer lugar obtendría los días en los que controlar la asistencia con esta simple consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fecha
  FROM asistencia;
```

Si no hay registros de una determinada fecha, es que ese día no habría que asistir o al menos no ha ido nadie.

También necesito un registro completo de asistentes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cedula
  FROM asistencia;
```

Y también debo realizar el producto cartesiano de ambos para que ningún asistente se quede sin fecha de asistencia:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT fecha
      FROM asistencia  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cedula
      FROM asistencia  
  ) c2;
```

Después, contabilizaría el número de registros por día de cada asistente:

```
SELECT fecha,cedula,COUNT(*) n
  FROM asistencia
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Y combinaría las dos últimas consultas para determinar los registros diarios de cada asistentes sin dejarme ningún día atrás:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT fecha
          FROM asistencia  
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT cedula
          FROM asistencia
      ) c2
  ) c3 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fecha,cedula,COUNT(*) n
      FROM asistencia
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c4 USING(fecha,cedula);
```

Con este resultado, en función de la `n`, ya podría determinar qué asistentes y en qué fecha han faltado o se han olvidado de fichar.

```
+------------+--------+------+
| fecha      | cedula | n    |
+------------+--------+------+
| 2022-08-20 |   1213 |    2 |
| 2022-08-21 |   1213 | NULL |
| 2022-08-20 |   1214 |    1 |
| 2022-08-21 |   1214 |    2 |
+------------+--------+------+
```

Se haría con un `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN n IS NULL THEN 'No asiste'
    WHEN n=1 THEN 'Se olvida de fichar'
    WHEN n=2 THEN 'Correcto'
  END asistencia
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT fecha
          FROM asistencia  
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT cedula
          FROM asistencia
      ) c2
  ) c3 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fecha,cedula,COUNT(*) n
      FROM asistencia
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c4 USING(fecha,cedula);
```

Obteniendo:

```
+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
| fecha      | cedula | n    | asistencia          |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
| 2022-08-20 |   1213 |    2 | Correcto            |
| 2022-08-21 |   1213 | NULL | No asiste           |
| 2022-08-20 |   1214 |    1 | Se olvida de fichar |
| 2022-08-21 |   1214 |    2 | Correcto            |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
```

O, incluso con un `WHERE` al final, quedándote con los casos que te interesen:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN n IS NULL THEN 'No asiste'
    WHEN n=1 THEN 'Se olvida de fichar'
    WHEN n=2 THEN 'Correcto'
  END asistencia
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT fecha
          FROM asistencia  
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT cedula
          FROM asistencia
      ) c2
  ) c3 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fecha,cedula,COUNT(*) n
      FROM asistencia
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c4 USING(fecha,cedula)
  WHERE n IS NULL OR n=1;

+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
| fecha      | cedula | n    | asistencia          |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
| 2022-08-21 |   1213 | NULL | No asiste           |
| 2022-08-20 |   1214 |    1 | Se olvida de fichar |
+------------+--------+------+---------------------+
```

Espero haber acertado, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.